# tracking data while redirecting form one site to another

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a 2 websites. In one website (website A) I have button that redirects to website B. I have added the google analytics code in website B. Whenever there is redirection form website A to website B . In the analytics report it is showing as direct in sources, how to make it as a referral .

Comment: Check if website A is in the referral exclusion list for website B (in the property settings).

Answer (score 0):

Are the 2 websites using the same GA ID? You can add campaign tracking (UTM parameters with Google URL builder) to the link or event tracking if you want to keep everything within one session.